# What is this big black bar at the bottom?

Tags: android, .net, xaml, maui

I am building an app in .NET MAUI. I started building it for a previous android version (API 22). The layout is fine for that version. But when I installed it on a later version of android (API 33), the vertical stack layout wasn't aligning as I wanted it to be.

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

I thought the problem was with how I arranged all these elements. So, I rewrote the XAML, but still didn't achieve what I was looking for. The black bar still remains at the bottom.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:WordsAssistantMAUI.ViewModels"
             x:DataType="viewmodels:DefinitionViewModel"
             x:Class="WordsAssistantMAUI.Views.DefinitionView"
             Title="Get Definition"
             BackgroundColor="#7d83cf">
    <VerticalStackLayout 
        VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="20,20" Spacing="20">

        <!--Search bar-->
        <SearchBar Text="{Binding Input}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsNotBusy}"
                   SearchCommand="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodels:DefinitionViewModel}}, Path=SearchDefinitionCommand}"/>
        
        <!--Definition and Navigation buttons-->
        <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*, 10*, *" 
              ColumnSpacing="15" VerticalOptions="Center" RowDefinitions="*,*">
            <Button Text="b" 
                    HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50" 
                    Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
                    Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodels:DefinitionViewModel}}, Path=PreviousDefinitionCommand}"/>
            <ScrollView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HeightRequest="125">
                <Label Text="{Binding Definition}"
                       Style="{StaticResource DefintionStyle}"/>
            </ScrollView>
            <Button Text="n"
                    Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"
                    HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50"
                    Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodels:DefinitionViewModel}}, Path=NextDefinitionCommand}"/>
            <ActivityIndicator 
                IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}"
                IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Grid.Row="1"/>
        </Grid>

        <!--Synonyms and Antonyms-->
        <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,*" Style="{StaticResource ResponsesListGrid}">
            <VerticalStackLayout Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                <Label Text="Synonyms"
                       Style="{StaticResource ResponsesLabel}"/>
                <Frame HeightRequest="300"
                       Style="{StaticResource ResponsesFrame}">
                    <ScrollView HorizontalOptions="Start">
                        <FlexLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding synonyms}"
                                    Style="{StaticResource ResponsesFlexLayout}">
                            <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Frame Style="{StaticResource ResponseStyling}">
                                        <Label Text="{Binding .}" Style="{StaticResource Responses}"/>
                                    </Frame>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                            <BindableLayout.EmptyViewTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Frame HasShadow="True" BackgroundColor="LightGray"
                                           Padding="5">
                                        <Label Style="{StaticResource Responses}"
                                            Text="Nothing to show right now!"/>
                                    </Frame>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </BindableLayout.EmptyViewTemplate>
                        </FlexLayout>
                    </ScrollView>
                </Frame>
            </VerticalStackLayout>

            <VerticalStackLayout Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                <Label Text="Antonyms"
                       Style="{StaticResource ResponsesLabel}"/>
                <Frame HeightRequest="300"
                       Style="{StaticResource ResponsesFrame}">
                    <ScrollView HorizontalOptions="Start">
                        <FlexLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding antonyms}"
                                    Style="{StaticResource ResponsesFlexLayout}">
                            <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Frame Style="{StaticResource ResponseStyling}">
                                        <Label Text="{Binding .}" Style="{StaticResource Responses}"/>
                                    </Frame>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                            <BindableLayout.EmptyViewTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Frame HasShadow="True" BackgroundColor="LightGray"
                                           Padding="5">
                                        <Label Style="{StaticResource Responses}"
                                            Text="Nothing to show right now!"/>
                                    </Frame>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </BindableLayout.EmptyViewTemplate>
                        </FlexLayout>
                    </ScrollView>
                </Frame>
            </VerticalStackLayout>
        </Grid>
        <Button Text="Clear all" WidthRequest="150"
                IsEnabled="{Binding IsNotBusy}"
                Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodels:DefinitionViewModel}}, Path=ClearAllCommand}"/>

    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: This only occurs on Android? What else have you done or changed?

Comment: Yes, only on the version I mentioned. But on API 22, it works totally fine.

Comment: How's your project configured? Have you set the Target SDK and API to Level 33?

Comment: Um no. I think its set to something below that.

Comment: You should always target the latest APIs. Sometimes, not only security features change, but also how things are displayed. Your app will still work on devices with lower API versions. This may, but doesn't have to be the reason. Still, it's recommended to always keep the target API up-to-date.

Comment: Try to replace the root VerticalStackLayout with a Scrollview and revert. Seems that VerticalStackLayout autosizes with your content.

Comment: @IsidorosMoulas Worth a try. I suspect that it won't be the cause, though, because the entire `ContentPage` doesn't expand over the available height. Otherwise, the empty area wouldn't be black but rather have the purple background color of the page. The composition of the page is quite complex, though and could probably be simplified.

Comment: @AmanatAziz What are all those `ScrollView` instances for? Try simplifying your XAML and remove everything that isn't strictly needed.

Comment: @AmanatAziz Try using a `Grid` as the root element (if you don't need scrolling on the root level) instead of a `StackLayout` and make sure it uses `VerticalOptions="Fill"`.

Comment: @ewerspej Thanks for the help. I set the target API to the latest one present (API 33 most likely). Now it's working fine on all platforms. And those scroll view instances are for scrolling through the list of synonyms and antonyms, and the definition when it is too long.